# Proper HTML technique to create an web form out of an image

Tags: html, css, forms, html-table, gimp

I plan to create an interactive golf score card for my website (XHTML). (Btw. thats how such a scorecard looks like: [ScoreCard](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/3d/Golf_Scorekarte.jpg)). So at the end one should be able to insert a score for each hole in the appropriated input field in the virtual scorecard on the website. For me it is very important that the interactive scorecard really looks the same as the original (paper-) scorecard does and so my first approach was to scan and slice the scorecard image to reach that appearance.

Here you can see the way I sliced the image:

[image]

The idea was to insert HTML text input for each score field ending up with something like this:

[image]

After I sliced the image I reconstructed it using the HTML . To do that I put the image slices as the cell background.

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td style="background: url("slice1.jpg") width="58px" height="25px">
      <input type="text"></inputText>
    </td>
  </tr>
  ...
</table>
```

At the first moment this worked fine (as Gimp offers quite a nice feature for this). Then the problem was that I had to create a HTML table  to create the exact layout. As you can see the lower part of the layout is split up into 3 columns. The middle column is split up into several (for each hole) rows. So the left and right column have to be spanned over those rows. Ok finally that worked, but it lead to some kind of scaling problem. If I zoom in or out on the table the middle column (and only that one) is not scaled the right way. I am not able to fix this, and so I start doubting if this is the right technique for html image virtualization. I am really no specialist in the area of creating websites, so I would really appreciate any help on this. Maybe there is a complete other and better technique to do that, as I think it is a common job in webcreation. I couldn't find any nice examples or tutorials on that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless I'm missing anything, you don't need to use any image slices, or any images at all to get this effect. This could all be done in plain CSS.

Heres a rough example of how this could be achieved:

http://jsfiddle.net/Curt/wxFtJ/

Comment: I want to use the scanned image to get the online form appearance as close as possible to the original scorecard. Can you give me any hint on how this could work out with using just plain css?

Comment: Can I just use the whole image as a div background and position my <inputs> in that div via css? I tried that before, but by zooming in and out the inputs got displaced on the image. any clue how to do that positioning the right way. Iam kind of css noob ;)

Comment: @Lars I've included an example in my answer.

Comment: @Curt - note that the actual image that OP linked to is [this](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/3d/Golf_Scorekarte.jpg)

Comment: thanks curt, that is all I wanted to know. thanks for your example as well. the table approach was probably nonsense. So my further investigations go in the div and css direction...

Answer (score 0):

You have one table with one row and one big cell with a background image now. Do you mean you want your HTML table to look like this:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td colspan="3">One row</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="3">One row</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="3">One row</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="3">One row</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="text"></td>
<td><input type="text"></td>
<td><input type="text"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="text"></td>
<td><input type="text"></td>
<td><input type="text"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="text"></td>
<td><input type="text"></td>
<td><input type="text"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="text"></td>
<td><input type="text"></td>
<td><input type="text"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="text"></td>
<td><input type="text"></td>
<td><input type="text"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Please read up on basic HTML table styling: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html

Also, you really shouldn't slice an image to create a table.

Comment: This isn't tabular data, so using `div`'s and CSS would be more appropriate.

Comment: @Dirk de Man: Of course this is the way I did it. The example in my post just showed the code of one single row. I tired to indicate that with the three dots (...) that there are even more rows.

Comment: Ah, so you want a multi-column layout just using CSS, and making it look like the scorecard? Have you read this article on Alistapart? http://www.alistapart.com/articles/practicalcss//